# ¿Se escribe "satisfactibilidad" o "satisfacibilidad?

Tags: ortografía

En teoría de computación se habla del [Problema de satisfacibilidad booleana](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_de_satisfacibilidad_booleana). En inglés se llama “satisfiability problem”, y se trata de determinar si una fórmula lógica se puede o no *satisfacer*. Sin embargo, como [la discusión misma en Wikipedia indica](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discusi%C3%B3n%3aProblema_de_satisfacibilidad_booleana), no es claro si se debe escribir `satisfacibilidad` o `satisfacTibilidad` con T.

Siendo un término técnico ninguna de las dos versiones aparece en la RAE, y buscando en Google Scholar la opinión al momento parece estar dividida entre [`satisfacibilidad` (208 publicaciones)](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=satisfacibilidad&hl=en&lr=lang_es&sciui=1&as_sdt=0,5) y [`satisfactibilidad` (173 publicaciones)](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=satisfactibilidad&hl=en&lr=lang_es&sciui=1&as_sdt=0,5).

¿Existe alguna razón ortográfica o etimológica para preferir alguna de las dos versiones? En un sentido práctico, ¿cuál de las dos es más “correcta” y se debería de usar?

---

**Actualización:** Aparentemente hay algunos pares de palabras similares donde la RAE acepta ambas ortografías con el mismo significado, como son el caso de:

- conducible/conductible
- reducible/reductible
- irreducible/irreductible

En general también parecen haber más palabras terminadas en -cible que en -ctible. ¿Podrá esto sugerir que ambas ortografías serían también aceptables?

Comment: Yo oigo mucho _satisfabilidad_, a todas luces incorrecto, pero es lo que hay...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En [este tweet](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1221733663550865409) de la RAE se mencionan ambas variantes como válidas en cuanto a derivadas de satisfacible/satisfactible

[image: RAE tweet]

Answer (score 3):

Dado que la palabra **[factibilidad](http://dle.rae.es/factibilidad)** (de **factible**) sí existe, y que la palabra que nos ocupa tiene la misma raíz y formación (hacer-facer), yo diría que la palabra correcta es **satisfactibilidad**.

Comment: estaba apunto de aceptar esta respuesta, pero he encontrado un nuevo argumento sugiriendo que ambas opciones podrían ser correctas, y en consecuencia he editado mi pregunta. ¿Qué opinas de lo que se dice?

Comment: No creo. La relación con "factible" no es una mera concidencia de terminación, es la misma palabra con distinto prefijo (satisfacer -> hacer, satisfecho -> hecho)

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que la palabra "satisfiability" no está en el Merrian-Webster y que ni "satisfacibilidad" ni "satisfacTibilidad" están en la RAE, cómo vas a valorar cual es la correcta? Son términos técnicos basados (en mi opinión, y soy también un técnico) en la pereza típica de la ciencia de no usar la formulación correcta pero más larga y optar por una palabra inventada pero más corta. Por lo general estas palabras inventadas las usan cuatro gatos y suelen ser bastante feas, por lo que no acaban en el diccionario.

Yo usaría satisfactibilidad por el origen latín (satisfactĭo, -ōnis).

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente, he escuchado ambos términos.  `Satisfacibilidad` es utilizado en documentos y/o libros técnicos, pero no necesariamente implica que `satisfactibilidad` esté incorrecto.  Similar a cómo en inglés las palabras `color` o `colour` varían, dependiendo de si es Estados Unidos o Inglaterra.  Tengo idea que el primer término es el "correcto", pero como indiqué, he escuchado ambos.